# Checking a number in a class and adding a class to it

Tags: javascript, class, webflow

I am new to coding and so I don't really what I am looking for. The problem is that I want to add a class to an existing class when hovering in and when I'm hovering out it should remove the class. Now I have three combo classes as you can see (.image-1, .image-2, .image-3) and I want to add the class "isplaying" to all of them individually because they have different content.

For now, I just duplicated the functions but do you know a more elegant or simpler way?

(I tried to use an if-statement to check the number in the string but it didn't work).

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
$(".category.image-1").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
$(".category.image-2").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
$(".category.image-3").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: You only need one function. Just use `$(".category")` as the selector. `$(this)` will be scoped to the current element.

Comment: If the `isplaying` class just changes styling properties, you can use CSS only instead of a JS onhover event. `.category.image-1:hover, .category.image-2:hover, .category.image-3:hover { ... add styling of isplaying... }`

Comment: You also could just use the :hover selector in your css instead of using javascript for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class in your selector to match the `image-` classes:

```
$(".category[class*='image-']").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
```

This will give you the elements that have the classes `category` and the `class` attribute also contains the following `image-`. This will match with all 3 (and any additional) of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: It is first important to make sure we don't have a case of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. That is, if you want to add different *styles* to an element on hover, and remove those on a mouseout, then maybe using the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class is a better choice.
>
> ```
> .category[class*='image-']:hover {
>   /* Insert hover styles here */
> }
> ```
>
> If `.isplaying` is doing more than basic styling, then using a JS is OK. However, if it is just styling, `:hover` might be the better choice.
>
> Moving on...

The code that you have is equivalent to the following:

```js
$(".category.image-1, .category.image-2, .category.image-3").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
```

If you *really do* want to keep the hover effects to elements that have the `.category` class **and** have an `image-$NUMBER` class, then you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) on the `class` attribute. Namely the `[attr*=value]` wildcard selector.

So a selector like `.category[class*="image-"]` will match any number tied to a `.image-` class.

```js
$(".category[class*='image-']").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
);
```

There are a couple of things to know about the `[attr*=value]` selector. Namely, that it'll match that string *wherever it may be.* So the `[class*="image-"]` selector will match an any of the elements below:

```
<div class="image-1"></div>
<div class="image-"></div>
<div class="some-other-image-1"></div>
<div class="image-something-else"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love the second way of doing it. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your elements share a common class, `.category`, this can be used as the selector for a single function.

`$(this)` will represent the current element.

```js
$(".category").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("isplaying");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
  }
)
```

```css
.category {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.isplaying {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="category category-1">
  Category 1
</div>
<div class="category category-2">
  Category 2
</div>
<div class="category category-3">
  Category 3
</div>
```

Of course, this could be done with CSS is all you want to do is change the style.

```css
.category {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.category:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="category category-1">
  Category 1
</div>
<div class="category category-2">
  Category 2
</div>
<div class="category category-3">
  Category 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to change the background image. Can I do this with css?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that with the common selector which is `.category` as using those `image-` classes are redundant.

```
$(".category").hover(
   function () {
     $(this).addClass("isplaying");
   },
   function () {
     $(this).removeClass("isplaying");
   }
)
```

Also, if you are only going to work on styling rather than logic in JS, you can better do it with just CSS as following:

```
.category:hover {
   // Your styling goes here
}
```

One more suggestion, don't use class for uniqueness. You can use ID for that purpose. `image-1`, `image-2` and so on are good for referencing IDs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. But I believe I can't solely use an ID because I'm working with Webflow and there I need to use combo classes to give the class categorie different images.